# Simple data collection application using JSON and .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, json

I'm building a web application that consists only of one page (Literally one page, no HTML generation). The whole purpose of this application is to collect data from users and then save it into a SQL Server database.

I want to use Javascript to validate and collect the data from the HTML Form, put it in a JSON object, and then use C# and .NET to insert the data into SQL Server.

I have no clear idea on how to achieve this, and honestly, I'm not really sure if this is a valid model or not!

Any pointers or ideas on what to look for and where to start? And how can I achieve this in the simplest way possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC.  Here is an example:

[Posting simple json to MVC action controller method with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989770/posting-simple-json-to-mvc-action-controller-method-with-jquery)

or this one:

[Send data to MVC controller using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496744/send-data-to-mvc-controller-using-json)